# IOS .sort function is not working

Tags: javascript

I have seen in other questions about the sort function not working on IOS devices because they are returning a boolean. That is not my case.

Here is my sort function:

`.sort((a, b) => (!a['@IsAvailable']) && b['@IsAvailable'] ? 1 : 0)`

This sorts correctly on everything except browsers hosted on apple products.

Comment: [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) expects not a boolean or just 1 or zero, but a value smaller then zero, zero or a value greater than zero. maybe you try this.

Comment: @NinaScholz so are you saying try a -1 instead of the 0?

Comment: i am not sure, what you like to sort ...

Answer (score 0):

The correct sort to be able to work on browsers hosted on Apple devices is:

`.sort((a, b) => (!a['@IsAvailable']) && b['@IsAvailable'] ? 1 : -1)`

Apple's interpretation of the sort function seems to group a 0 value with 1 or more.